# Is there a point to Oauth2.0 Credentials option for Chrome Extensions when the latter doesn't support redirects?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I've been trying to enable Oauth2.0 authentication for a Google chrome extension. Had I stuck to a simple web server approach, I'd have saved a lot of time. But when I saw that Google APIs & Services Console had Oauth2.0 credentials for Chrome extension, I thought it might save me sometime (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) but I was wrong.
Here is where I could set-up auth2.0 credentials for a chrome extension.
[image: [Google APIs Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0geti.png)]

I'm not particularly experienced in working with Chrome extensions but tried nevertheless. I've spent an absurd amount of time in trying to figure out a way to get this done. Chrome extensions can't do redirect URLs which is basically the response for Oauth2.0 final step. I've followed these examples - [Chrome Identity API] (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/app_identity/) which uses this for initiating auth :

```
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({ interactive: true, 'url': authURL }, function (redirect_url) {
      console.log(redirect_url);
```

vs

[Chrome Extensions + OAuth usage Example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_oauth/). which uses the following for auth :

```
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
      console.log(token);
    });
```

Both automatically set the redirect URL to https://.chromiumapp.org/ (as per the 1st example, Chrome automatically reads a URL based on its prefix and redirects it to a callback? So chrome does redirects sometimes?? Anyways, it didn't work. This is a snippet from the example: "*The  provider will perform authentication and if appropriate, will show login and/or approval UI to the user. It will then redirect to https://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb#authToken=
Chrome will capture that and invoke the callback of the app with the full redirect URL. The app should extract the token out of the URL.*") so you get a mismatch redirect URL error immediately in the first example, presumably it opens in a popup window for auth (Google I believe disallows this & therefore shows a redirect URL error on it) and in the second example, it redirects you **after authentication but before consent page** to www.google.com.

After trying and spending quite some time, I just went ahead and used Firebase to make my life easier which implements Oauth2.0 at its end to manage redirect URIs [assuming it creates services accounts with full permissions to generate Oauth2.0 web credentials and API keys] and just gives a simple access token. This, as opposed to, me setting a server, managing redirect requests, getting auth code, then tokens & then sending them to the chrome extension (here's where I've been testing https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Please do let me know if I'm missing something here in terms of using Oauth2.0 + Chrome extensions.

Thanks in advance.